# Solving Recurrence Equation $T(n)=2T(\frac{n}{2})+2$

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, asymptotics

### Question

> Solve Recurrence Equation
>
> $$T(n)=2T(\frac{n}{2})+2$$
>
> $\text{Base case a)}T(1)=1\,\,b)T(2)=1$

$\text{I am trying to solve one of the algorithm problem for which both the Base}$
$\text{cases hold, but i am getting different solution .Hence , i want to verify}$
$\text{if i am solving recurrences correctly or not.}$

#### My Approach/Solution

$T(n)=2T(\frac{n}{2})+2............(1)$

$T(\frac{n}{2})=2T(\frac{n}{4})+2............(2)$

$T(\frac{n}{4})=2T(\frac{n}{8})+2............(3)$

Using $(2),(3)$ in $(1)$,

$T(n)=8T(\frac{n}{8})+8+4+2$

In generalised form,

$T(n)=2^{k}T(\frac{n}{2^{k}})+2^{k}+....+2^{3}+2^{2}+2^{1}$

$T(n)=2^{1}\times (2^{k}-1)+2^{k}T(\frac{n}{2^{k}}).....(4)$

USing base case (a) i.e $T(1)=1 \Rightarrow \frac{n}{2^{k}}=1 \Rightarrow k=\log n$
Using value of $k=\log n$ in $(4)$

> $T(n)=2^{1}\times (2^{k}-1)+2^{k} \times T(1)$
>
> $T(n)=2^{1}\times (2^{k}-1)+2^{k}$
>
> $T(n)=2\times (2^{\log n }-1)+2^{\log n}$
>
> $$T(n)=2\times (n-1)+n=3n-2$$

---

USing base case (b) i.e $T(2)=1 \Rightarrow \frac{n}{2^{k}}=2 \Rightarrow k=\log n-1$
Using value of $k=\log n-1$in $(4)$

> $T(n)=2^{1}\times (2^{k}-1)+2^{k} \times T(2)$
>
> $T(n)=2^{1}\times (2^{k}-1)+2^{k}$
>
> $T(n)=2\times (2^{\log n -1 }-1)+2^{\log n-1}$
>
> $T(n)=2\times (\frac{2^{\log n }}{2}-1)+\frac{2^{\log n}}{2}$
>
> $$T(n)=2\times (\frac{3n-4}{2}$$

Am i correct for both the base cases?
Please help

Comment: How to get $T(3)$ for your recurrsive relation?

Comment: $T(3)=3\times3-2=7$

Comment: I don understand how you got $T(3)$..

Comment: I used the equation that i got using base case (a) ,that is what my question is , i am not sure if i am right

Comment: Ahhhh i get , it will not work for odd cases

Comment: it is $$T(n)=1+\frac{\log(n)}{\log(2)}$$